# Property types in public interface and extension

Tags: objective-c, types, properties, attributes

I have a couple of related questions about Objective-C properties, but first let's look at a little code:

This is the public interface for the class:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property(retain, readonly) ParentType* aVariable;

@end
```

And in the implementation I define a class extension:

```
@interface SomeClass ()

@property(retain) ChildType* aVariable;

@end
```

I know that I can do this kind of thing to make "aVariable" read-write in the implementation, but I have two questions:

1. Is using a child type of the property in the class extension acceptable? Will this work?
2. Do I need to keep the retain attribute in the class extension? Or does redeclaring the property clear all those attributes?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Typo

Comment: Are you using ARC? If so you should use strong instead of retain.

Comment: @FabienWarniez Under ARC, `retain` is a synonym for `strong`.

Comment: You are right, but I just like strong better, and retain reminds me of the old way of doing things, when you actually had to call "retain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, and it is recommended. If you want to see if it works you could just try it.
2. They have to match, so you have to add it again. The only thing that can change between the public and private declaration is "readonly".